# Using Objective-C function in Swift which takes in a reference to a variable

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a Objective-C function which we'll call foo for the purposes of being useful to others.

```
something a //Define variable a as a 'something' type
[foo:&a]
```

How do I go about translating this into swift?

Comment: What is `something`? A scalar type, struct, union, class, ...? What does `foo`? How is the method declared? Does it modify the referenced element? – A concrete compiling example would be helpful.

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness. 'a' is a class in a SDK which foo, also part of the sdk, would reference to in this case return a modified class object containing error codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swift if you want to pass by reference you use the `inout` notation in your function definition

such as

```
func test(inout a : Double) {
    //do something
}

var d : Double = 3.5
test(&d)
```

If you are referring to using a function directly you would use the same `&variable` notation you use elsewhere

So you would just call `foo(&var)`

Answer (score 0):

If the `something` is an instance of a class, it is automatically pass by reference when you do:

```
foo(a)
```

If the `something` is an instance of a struct, it's passed in as a copy and you shouldn't try to pass it's address around. Instead make `something` a class.